# How to store several pieces of info in a defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a list I'm iterating over to tally up some combinations, and I'd like to store some more info beyond the tallies. A `Counter` or `defaultdict` is good for tallies but I'm not sure how to add the aux info. For instance if I'm toting up all length-2 lists in my `'list_to_count'` column I can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'auxinfo': ['first', 'second', 'third'], 'list_to_count': [['apple', 'banana'], ['apple', 'banana', 'chicken'], ['apple']]})
print(mydf)
d=defaultdict(int)
for r in mydf.itertuples():
    combos = combinations(r.list_to_count, 2)
    for combo in combos:
        combo_name = ','.join(sorted(combo))
        d[combo_name] += 1
print(d)
```

This is what I get:

```
auxinfo              list_to_count
0        first       [apple, banana]
1        second      [apple, banana, chicken]
2        third       [apple]
```

```py
In [13]: d
Out[13]: defaultdict(int, {'apple,banana': 2, 'apple,chicken': 1, 'banana,chicken': 1})
```

But I'd also like to store the `auxinfo` e.g. in a list, where the desired output would look like

```py
{'apple,banana': (2, ['first', 'second']), 'apple,chicken': (1, ['second']), 'banana,chicken': (1, ['second'])}
```

The `defaultdict` can be intialized like `defaultdict(tuple)` in which I could store a tuple of `(count, auxinfo_list)` but the `auxinfo_list` itself isn't a `defaultdict`.

Comment: The desired output has invalid syntax.

Comment: yeah, looks like someone corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and set the *default* value to `(0, [])`.

```py
d = {}
for r in mydf.itertuples():
    combos = combinations(r.list_to_count, 2)
    for combo in combos:
        combo_name = ','.join(sorted(combo))
        count, auxinfo_list = d.get(combo_name, (0, []))
        d[combo_name] = (count + 1, auxinfo_list + [r.auxinfo])

for key, value in d.items():
    print(f'{key}:\t{value}')
```

Output:

```
apple,banana:   (2, ['first', 'second'])
apple,chicken:  (1, ['second'])
banana,chicken: (1, ['second'])
```

Comment: that dog will hunt